# O que está errado no código jQuery que escrevi?

Tags: jquery

Olá, amigos! Sou novato em programação, e gostaria de ajuda para identificar um problema na construção de um código para criar um botão "Vá para o topo da página", com animação, em jQuery.

O que escrevi parece correto, mas depois que ele é acionado uma vez, a barra de rolagem fica agarrada no topo e não sai mais.

Seguem os trechos de HTML, CSS e JQUERY, para análise:

**HTML**

```
<button id="bt-top" type="submit" title="Vá para o topo da página │ Vaya a la parte superior de la página │ Aller en haut de la page"> ▲ </button>
```

**CSS**

```
#bt-top {
display: none;
position: fixed;
font-size: 18pt;
bottom: 12px;
right: 12px;
color: #fff;
border: solid 3px #fff;
background-color: #00b7ce;
cursor: pointer;
padding-bottom: 6px;
/* - - - - - - - - - */
border-radius: 12px; /* CSS3 */
    -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* Firefox */
        -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Chrome, Safari */
/* - - - - - - - - - */
width: 54px;
z-index: 999; }

#bt-top:hover { background-color: #6b6b6b; }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) 
    {

        $("#bt-top").css({"display" : "block"});
    } 
    else 
    {
        $("#bt-top").css({"display" : "none"});
    }

    $("#bt-top").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#principal").offset().top}, 2400);

    }); }); });
```

Desde já, grato pela ajuda,

Alexandre Soares

Comment: Pode usar `$("#bt-top").show()` para exibir e `$("#bt-top").hide()` para esconder.

Comment: Obrigado! Vou testar essa possibilidade! Valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que você está criando um novo evento toda vez que a barra de rolagem é utilizada. Como a quantidade de eventos criados é alta, então o código vai ficar repetindo o mesmo processo (de levar a página até o topo) várias e várias vezes.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {

      $("#bt-top").css({
        "display": "block"
      });
    } else {
      $("#bt-top").css({
        "display": "none"
      });
    }


  });
});

/* É necessário deixar o código abaixo fora do evento `scroll` */
$("#bt-top").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#principal").offset().top
  }, 2400);
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 1000px;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="principal">
<button id="bt-top">Topo</button>

<div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Agora está funcionando! Valeu!